# Watco lacquer still gummy after 4 days

Tags: finishing, technique, wood

I am a jewelry artist who recently started working with wood. I have used a gold stamping ink to lightly cover a few pieces, allowed to dry completely for 24 hours and then started doing mist coats of Watco semi-gloss lacquer on them. It seems that after the 6th coat (over 2 days) the pieces went from feeling almost cured to gummy. I have hung them in a box and pointed a fan at them for going on 3 days now. Some pieces have cured but others have not hardended even a little bit. Any advice for me?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. This is a hard one as there are a few possible causes, and the gold stamping ink seems like it could possibly be a factor. The main thing I want to check, is the wood the same in all cases or did you use a variety? If so, is it the same wood with all the problem pieces? Regardless of this, the main recommendation with this kind of problem would normally be to try and wait longer as occasionally drying is retarded for some reason. After 3 full days with a fan going and no apparent improvement though there's a chance that the worst ones will stay permanently tacky.